# Nifi - Groovy Json Script define null attributes

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have a Nifi Groovy Script. Assigns fields to nifi attributes but it define null if json values ​​are empty. if json value is null I want to define attribute empty.

null attributes look like this ;

[image]

I want to like this ;

[image]

this is the script i use ;

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*
def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
    return;
}
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def attrs = [:] as Map<String,String>
session.read(flowFile,
    { inputStream ->
        def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        def obj = slurper.parseText(text)
        obj.each {k,v ->
           attrs[k] = v.toString()
        }
    } as InputStreamCallback)
flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attrs)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is i solved it ;

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*
def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
    return;
}
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def attrs = [:] as Map<String,String>
session.read(flowFile,
    { inputStream ->
        def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        def obj = slurper.parseText(text)
        obj.each {k,v ->

          if (v.toString()=="null")
          {
            attrs[k] = ''
          } else {
            attrs[k] = v.toString()
          }

        }
    } as InputStreamCallback)
flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attrs)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attrs.collectEntries{k,v->[k,v?:'']})
```

Comment: i got an error ; 
ExecuteGroovyScript[id=01841011-21f7-17f3-3f20-e267910070a8] groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.GroovyProcessSessionWrap.putAllAttributes() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.GroovySessionFile, ArrayList) values: [WRAP[StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=0d722ced-0e23-4f0f-a8b4-0026fbadcb6c,claim=StandardContentClaim